I need help setting up a Fireblocks MPC as a Safe signer
so far I've been following the steps on this link (https://forum.safe.global/t/self-custody-with-multi-party-computation-as-a-safe-signer/2267/5) but I can't seem to get the signature prompting in FB.
Surely I'm missing something.
Any help is greatly appreciated ! Many thanks in advance :)

It seems that your safe was deployed before adding the MPC addresses as signers. Could you try again following the exact steps described in the post?
You should then be prompted in Fireblocks to sign messages and transactions coming from your Safe the same way than confirming any other message or transaction.
Could you please confirm that this is working correctly? Thanks in advance 
Louis

Hi Louis, thanks for your response. Actually, for the Safe I have deployed in Base Sepolia I added the signers at deployment.
I believe there's something not correctly set up within FB's TAPs. Initially, set the type to RAW but I'm thinking it should be "Contract Call (Approved & Typed)". Can you please confirm ?
Are you on TG ? I can share the TAPs in place in more detail (it does not allow me to attach image here).
Thank you!
